# Javascript alert window Based on Given time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Stored my data in a array in that data i have some data with today's date with upcoming time. I separated the date and time, how can i set the time for alert or popup window.(It should automatically trigger on that time and popup or alert window should come)

Can i achieve this using Set timeout Function()

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you can use setTimeout function:

```
setTimeout(function(){
//do the stuff
},newSeconds-oldSeconds);
```

Where, newSeconds is a variable whose value is tomorrow date in seconds and oldSeconds is today date in seconds.

**No**, you should not use setTimeout function:

The visitor won't wait for the event to occur on that time once the visitor opened the browser. So you should first calculate the seconds by deducting newSeconds and oldSeconds then use the event if the time reaches:

```
var currentSeconds = $.now().getSeconds();
if(currentTime == eventTime){ //eventTime is newSeconds - oldSeconds
//do stuff here
}
```

Comment: For example now time is 12:46pm and i want to set the alert to 1:00pm.. It automatically triggers at 1pm or we reduce the alerttime-currenttime

Comment: You can use .getSeconds() method for both date and use...

Comment: setTimeout will lag. For longer periods it's probably best to either sync with server every now and then or use client side `new date()` to fix the lag.(also depending on what kind of time you want to use, not everyones time is the same!)

Comment: @RenéGeuze you're right, and also it would better to use setInterval for getting $.now() value....

Answer (score 1):

Check this one..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body onLoad="myFunction()">

    <p>wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")}, 3000);
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```